# Use a setStatus($arg) function or have separate enable() and disable() functions?

Tags: coding-style, dry

I've got two functions at the moment:

```
suspendGroupsAndUsers($groupId){}
enableGroupsAndUsers($groupId) {}
```

But the difference between the two is one variable/string.  Should I just have:

```
setStatusGroupsAndUsers($status,$groupID) {}
```

This feels more DRY...  Or have the above two functions actually call the setStatus function?

Gut says use setStatus ...

Comment: Related, if not an exact duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior

Answer (score 1):

If your status can eventually become something else than a boolean value (enabled, suspended, hidden, banned, etc.), you may have to refactor if you only use `setStatus`.